# What is wrong with this code (groovy)

Tags: groovy

This piece of code takes a series of numbers and then prints out the highest one inputted. There is supposedly a flaw in the code which for a certain series of numbers will not produce the right output. However I can't find any series of numbers where the right output is not displayed and can't see the problem in the code.

```
int m = 0
boolean finished = false
while (!finished) {
    print "Enter another number (0 to finish): "
    String s = System.console().readLine()
    int num = Integer.parseInt(s)
    if (num != 0) {
        if (num > m) {
            m = num
        }
    } else {
        finished = true
    }
}
println m
```

Comment: Your code is expecting an integer. Try some very small floating-point numbers (less than 1.0) to see how they parse as an Integer.

Comment: Ok thanks this did cross my mind. However I assumed that question was implying that there was an issue when integers were inputted.

Would it be possible to change this code so that it would work with both integers and floating-point numbers?

Comment: Groovy is not my language, but I when I see typed variables and user input that is not validated, my immediate question is: what happens when the input does not match the declared type? You might also have a look at the behavior of your code with negative numbers.

Comment: Everything seems to be working as expected with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You answered that yourself - negative numbers are the culprit. This is a fixed version:

```
Integer m = null
boolean finished = false
while (!finished) {
   print "Enter another number (0 to finish): "
   String s = System.console().readLine()
   Integer num = Integer.parseInt(s)
   if (num != 0) {
      if (num > m) {
         m = num
      }
   } else {
      finished = true
  }
}
println (m == null ? "No input provided" : m)
```